# Dynamic type conversion with mirrors

Tags: dart, dart-mirrors

Problem:

Is it possible to cast dynamically to a type?

For example, could this be possible, using mirrors:

```dart
var reflectee = im.getField(simpleName).reflectee;

var converted = testVal as reflectee.runtimeType;
```

Context:
I want to make a Mixin class which defines a `validate` method:

```dart
abstract class Validatable {
  bool validate(Map document) {
  }
}
```

It will iterate over the variables defined for the class where it is mixed in, and checks if the variable in the document are of the same type.

Now, it is working with getting the `runtimeType` of the respective variables, but it is very restrictive as it does not cast. For example:

```dart
var a = 1.1;
var b = 1;
print(a.runtimeType == b.runtimeType); // false
```

It would be better to better to check with `as`, but I cant see how to get this to work. Becase:

```dart
a = b;
print(a.runtimeType); // int
```

and not double, as one might expect.

Is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use

```dart
import 'dart:mirrors';

class A {

}

class B extends A {

}

class C extends A {

}

void main(args) {
  var a = 1.1;
  var b = 1;
  var x = reflect(b);
  print(x.type.isSubtypeOf(reflectType(num)));
  print(x.type.isAssignableTo(reflectType(num)));
  print(x.type.isAssignableTo(reflectType(double)));

  var myb = new B();

  print(reflect(myb).type.isSubtypeOf(reflectType(A)));
  print(reflect(myb).type.isAssignableTo(reflectType(A)));
  print(reflect(myb).type.isAssignableTo(reflectType(C)));    
}
```

Comment: I think `isSubtypeOf` and `isAssignableTo` are rather new.

Comment: I was just wondering how to go about ``implements``. Because then, strictly speaking, we are not talking about a subtype.

Comment: I have tried it: `B implements D` makes `myb` subtype and assignable to `D`. If it implements an interface it can `be` of that type. I think `isSubtypeOf` includes `is`.

Comment: I was running 1.1.3 of the SDK, and I see that 1.2 is out, so the addition was that new.

Comment: 1.3.0 will be released very soon.

Comment: I checked some more with the new function calls, with ``Map`` and ``ObservableMap`` as types, where ``ObservableMap`` implements ``Map``. According to the documentation, it's true as you say, that ``isSubclass`` tests an ``is``. However, none of the methods mention that they test an ``as``, neither ``ObservableMap isAssignableTo Map`` reports as true. Maybe 1.3 will bring some highlights?

Comment: I tried it with ObservableMap and subtype and assignable report `true` (Dart VM version: 1.3.0-dev.7.10 (Thu Apr  3 01:00:43 2014) on "linux_x64")

Comment: I tested v1.3 now also. It still reports false for me. Here's the code I use:
(http://pastebin.com/BVBj56Mm)

Comment: This didn't work for me too `var aa = reflect(a).type;`. It seems you have to get the `TypeMirror` using `reflectType(x)` to make it work. I have yet to figure out what is the difference.

Comment: Ok, I understand. When you use `reflect(new Map()).type` you get `ClassMirror on '_LinkedHashMap'` for `reflectType(Map)` you get `ClassMirror on 'Map'`. You can't assign a `Map` to a `LinkedHashMap` because a `LinkedHashMap` is more specialised. The actual runtime type is different from the type used on `new`.

Comment: If I do this: ``var AA = reflectType(a.runtimeType);`` and test for the same, I still only get ``false``. With both SDK versions. I updated the pastebin to show exactly what I am doing.

Comment: when `a` is an instance of `ObservableMap` this prints true: `  var AA = reflectType(a.runtimeType);
  print(AA.isAssignableTo(reflectType(Map)));
  print(reflectType(Map).isAssignableTo(AA));
`

Comment: Ah yes. The code I posted is checking on the underlying type, not Map itself. So it's back to the ``as`` problem, without knowing explicitly the types of either of the objects and to find out whether one implements the other.

Comment: I think you have just to check all types (aa, aa.mixin, aa.superinterfaces) if they are assignable.